# RGB LED common cathode with 3.3V GPIO +single transistor

Tags: led, analog, circuit-design

You can control a RGB common anode like this with only one transistor and 3.3V GPIO sources:

[image]

How can you do this with a **common cathode LED array** using only one transistor per LED and 3.3V GPIOs?

The forward voltage of the LEDs are 3.6V

Comment: note: in the circuit above, the resistors should be between the LEDs and the collectors

Answer (score 4):

The temptation is to invert the circuit but this will fail.

[image]

*Figure 1. The protection diodes on most logic chips creates a sneak-path to positive supply. This will keep the PNP transistor permanently turned on and may damage the chip. Source: [High-side fail](http://lednique.com/gpio-high-side-driver-fail/).*

You need to add a second transistor.

[image]

*Figure 2. To drive a high-side transistor from a GPIO pin we need a level translator. An NPN transistor does the job nicely.*

There is a little more information in my article in the link.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using a 20mA drive for the LEDs.

Based on that you could use a single BJT in this manner:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRoSSe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Notice that no matter whether the LED is ON or OFF there is current drawn from the supply ….providing this is not a showstopper for you then it's quite usable.

When the LED is OFF (BJT is ON) there is actually more current flowing (28mA), but if you want to reduce this disparity, you could add a resitor to the BJT collector.